# Mapping the Rules & Metrics in Sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to find out a way of mapping between Rules in SonarQube (Declared on Different Languages) and given lists of Metrics (Complexity, maintainability, Reliability, etc). Is there any way to find such categorization in Sonarqube!

Comment: Indeed, I want to know if the measures like  Reliability, Duplication, etc are linked with Rules defined per language!

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer : There are no such mapping.

Some rules might rely on those metrics (for instance an issue can be raised if coverage is <= X% (even though it is better to rely on quality gate for this)) but those metrics are distinct from rules.

Comment: But the result of sonar analysis has been divided in terms of those metrics, so here some could think that  how can I link the Rules that I defined and causing some error which came under specific metric. Because what I felt was like I need to know the interpretation of the certain rule which I define....In fact, I am new to sonar and I am also trying to figure out some code quality model assessment so I thought such information can resolve my confusion while applying the tool.

Comment: I am sorry but I actually don't understand what is your issue here. Try to explain it differently.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that why sonar uses such categorization under the source code analysis but there is not way to link them to the Rules which I guess are the basis for Analysis

Comment: I think I am conflating the Rules and metrics together, Because I thought  there should be a kind of break down hierarchy between Rules and Metrics, but by what  you say it seems metrics are included in the core and they will be applied on source code analysis in a separate level!

Comment: Metrics and rules are different concepts. Metrics are measurement on your code (number of lines, lines of code etc). Rules are detecting patterns that are considered bad on your code. Most of the patterns rely on your source code to raise issue (ie:"you should not call this method in this context") and some of them rely on metrics to raise issue ("too many lines in this file").

Comment: Sorry If I am not able to deliver my message properly, Let me ask this question. We can disable certain Rules, is there a way to disable duplication check or complexity check!

Comment: Yes, because those are rules based on metrics: https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#languages=java|repositories=common-java metrics will be computed no matter what.

Comment: Then, Complexity will be checked always  as part of analysis cycle !

Comment: I meant cant we disable the certain measure as well?

Comment: Dear Benzonico, Many thanks for your support and useful comments can you help me out in the last comment, which states the possibility of disabling the metrics like rules!